# How to use a symbol only if it is defined

Tags: clojure

I would like to execute some Clojure code that depends upon a certain var, but **only if that var is defined**. As a simplified example, the body of the `if` form should only be executed if `sym` is defined:

```
(if (resolve 'sym) (println sym))
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. If `sym` is not defined, the compiler still tries to resolve it and throws:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: sym in this context
```

From reading Rich Hickley's comment [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2467359), I gathered that this behavior is due to Clojure's use of (mostly) single-pass compilation. However, as much sense as that makes, it obviously results in undesirable behavior in this case.

I can get around the problem by forcing the symbol resolution to happen at runtime:

```
(if (resolve 'sym) (println (deref (resolve 'sym))))
```

But this is an undesirable hack. Is there a better way, or is it not possible with Clojure's read-eval model?

*(Why do I need to do this? I have multiple composable profiles defined in my [`profiles.clj`](https://github.com/raxod502/dotfiles/blob/master/profiles.clj). One of them is for [vinyasa](https://github.com/zcaudate/vinyasa), which allows me to inject various functions into the conveniently accessible `.` namespace. Others load various other utility libraries. In the profiles for those other utility libraries, I want to use vinyasa to inject the most important functions, **but only if vinyasa is loaded**. I am [currently using](https://github.com/raxod502/dotfiles/blob/55ff74317c694536ee2bcd8758c1ab32edf988c4/profiles.clj#L92) a variation of the hack above.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach recommended by @Michiel with [`when-let`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/when-let) is the best way to solve this problem. Importantly, you can make the conditionality almost completely transparent by using [`let`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/let)'s ability to shadow an existing binding:

```
(when-let [foo (resolve 'foo)]
  (foo))
;;=> nil

(defn foo []
  :bar)

(foo)
;;=> :bar

(when-let [foo (resolve 'foo)]
  (foo))
;;=> :bar
```

Comment: This is very interesting! It's not immediately obvious what is going on here, but it seems that if you call a Var as a function, it derefs itself and then calls the function it points to. Notably, this means that if you want to use this trick for Vars that are not functions, you have to deref them by hand—but you don't have to for Vars that are functions.

Comment: @RadonRosborough Yep, that's exactly right; you can verify this by checking the [Var source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Var.java#L374-L376).

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn get-when-var-defined [sym]
  (when-let [var-for-sym (resolve sym)] 
    @var-for-sym))

(get-when-var-defined 'foo) ;;=> nil
(def foo 1)
(get-when-var-defined 'foo) ;;=> 1
```

Comment: Hmmm… so, basically, the same as what I have, but abstracted into a function? I guess that's reasonable enough; I'll accept this presently if no alternate solutions are presented.

Comment: you don't have to use a function of course. `(when-let [v (resolve 'sym)] @v])` is the most basic version of this